# In a nested if loop, how to return true for multiple matching conditions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the below program, even though all the if conditions are matching, it returns true just once. How do i make it return true and print as many times as the conditions match?

```
lotto_numbers = [1,1,1]
fireball_number = 1
user_input1 = user_input2 = user_input3 = 1

def fbcheck():
    if lotto_numbers == [user_input1,user_input2,fireball_number]:
        return True
    elif lotto_numbers == [fireball_number, user_input2, user_input3]:
        return True
    elif lotto_numbers == [user_input1, fireball_number, user_input3]:
        return True
    else:
        return False

if (fbcheck() == True):
    print ('you won')
```

Comment: `return sorted(lotto_numbers) == sorted([user_input1,user_input2,fireball_number])` ??

Comment: Why do you want it to have degrees of `True`ness to it? It's either true or it isn't. Can you give us a little idea of what you're trying to do, and the logic behind the ordering of those numbers.

Comment: I'm new to programming, I'm trying out a lotto program which rewards user multiple times if multiple conditions are matching. This is one of the conditions that I'm testing against. Hence hardcoded the lotto_numbers and fireball_number. Will add my actual code also for reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `all`:

```
def fbcheck():
    user_data = [user_input1,user_input2,fireball_number]

    lotto_numbers = [1,1,1]

    print([a==b for a, b in zip(lotto_numbers, user_data)])

    return all(a==b for a, b in zip(lotto_numbers, user_data))



print(fbcheck())
```

Output:

```
[True, True, True]

True
```